# Using references in Windows Mobile app prevents app from closing process

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

My app will be removed from the processes list when I do not add any references, but when I add a reference to `wmplib.dll` in the project, pressing the Exit button doesn't remove it from the processes list on a Windows Mobile device.

I used this code in my project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
private void Exit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Program.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace radiotest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [MTAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Windows Phone" and Windows Mobile, are two different things.  You might be confusing people with that title and not getting any responses...

Comment: Tagging it [tag:windows-ce] doesn't help either. Makes it worse in fact...